# How to import Objective C static library to Swift Framework?

Tags: macos, swift, frameworks, static-libraries

I’m writing a dynamic Framework (`Proto.framework`) for OS X in Swift. I want to include code from a static library (`libstat.a`) which is written in Objective C. Here’s what I’ve got:

```
// Dynamic.swift in Proto.framework
class Dynamic {
    func doSomethingWithStat() {
        Stat().statThing()
    }
}

// Stat.h in libstat.a static library
@interface Stat : NSObject
- (void)statThing;
@end

// Stat.m
@implementation Stat
- (void)statThing {
    NSLog(@"OK");
}
@end
```

In my target for Proto.framework, I have linked it to libstat.a. When I try to build Proto, naturally it doesn’t compile because it can’t find the definition for `Stat().statThing()`. It doesn’t know the symbols for my static library. How do I tell it about that?

For applications, I’d use a bridging header and do `#import <Stat/Stat.h>`. But the compiler errors out and tells me `Bridging headers aren’t allowed in frameworks`. OK.

So I include it in my “umbrella header” (`Proto.h`) but that tells me `error: include of non-modular header inside framework module`. OK.

Making my `Stat` library target `Defines module: YES` doesn’t seem to change the error even after a clean build. So I’m not sure how to do this.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you managed to figure this out eventually? I am struggling with the same issue.

Comment: Same problem here. Any solution?

Comment: I have the same problem. Still looking...

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way to accomplish that is to use a module map file. Below I assume you have the `Proto.framework` in a separate project, which is called `Proto`.

1. Create a `module.modulemap` file in your framework containing the following (substitute the path to the header file as needed):

_

```
framework module Proto {
    umbrella header "Proto.h"

    // Load a C header to be used in Swift - here /usr/include/sys/stat.h:
    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/sys/stat.h"

    export *
    module * { export * }
}
```

2. In your project build settings find `Module Map File` in section `Packaging`. Enter `$(SRCROOT)/Proto/module.modulemap`

That's it. From now on you should be able to use anything declared in `stat.h` in Swift.

Comment: not seeing a module map setting in Xcode 7.2 either unfortunately

Comment: @MaxMacLeod just create a new file in a text editor (TextWrangler for example) and drag n drop it to your project. Don't forget to select the target.

Comment: Did it worked for archiving the app as well?, after adding module.map I could resolve the issue of "include of Non modular headers" , But When I archive the project it does not find the bridging header file. complain for missing header. When I check build folder for release in derived data I dont see any hedaer file there. which was present before adding module map. any idea? I am working on xcode 10

Answer (score 2):

In your build settings for `Proto.framework` try setting the option `Allow Non-modular Includes In Framework Modules` to `Yes`.

[image: Xcode Settings]

Comment: Just gave it a shot and still getting `error: include of non-modular header inside framework module Proto` :\

Comment: I have the same problem (xcode 7, swift 2). Anyone find a solution?

Comment: I had to make the additional header public that I was importing inside the umbrella header

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this error by making the header Public (instead of Project)

Go to your target Build Phases and move the header accordingly:

[image: Header visibility settings]

This works for my 'lib' target. But I am still unable to build libTests target. Here I get 2 errors:

- 'header.h' file not found with  include; use "quotes" instead
- and again: Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'lib'

this I am not able to resolve yet